# Is It Possible to Use a Shared Pointer for the Parent of a QObject?

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

I have a startup class as such which sets up a `SystemController`in the construct:

```
m_systemController(new SystemController(this,
                                                 Provider::getSettingsAsSingleton())),
```

Essentially this satisfies:

```
public:
        explicit SystemController(QObject *parent,
                                  Settings& config);
```

I've recently though wanted to use this class in a threaded class, which doesn't like me passing me the `SystemController` as the threaded class doesn't have a parent. I tried passing it as such:

```
public:
explicit DataTestWorker(QObject *parent=0);//,
                                //SystemController &sysCtrl); //Obviously in my setup, it would complain about this
```

Where the `DataTestWorker` class is in fact the threaded class, initialised in a `DataTest` class. The reason I want to pass the memory location of the `SystemController`, is the Controller class has important data already setup in the class, which I wish to access without having to run all my initialisation methods within it again.

Is there a way to somehow pass it some sort of "shared" pointer - in which not only this class - but other classes can access it. The only way around this I can think of is I could use signals and slots between the `DataTest` and the `DataTestWorker` class to manipulate the values in the `SystemController`, but this would be long and verbose.

Any ideas? If you need anymore information, just ask.

Comment: don't use singletons. Bad idea in 99.9% of cases.

Comment: @UmNyobe - any ideas on what to do then?

Comment: `I've recently though wanted to use this class in a threaded class, which doesn't like me passing me the SystemController as the threaded class doesn't have a parent` This line is quite hard to understand

Comment: The `DataTestWorker `class does not have a parent. If I pass the `SystemController` into it, the compiler complains that I cannot pass it the address of the `SystemController` as `DataTestWorker` has no parent. It works if I create a new instance of `SystemController` in `DataTestWorker` but that defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do. Is that clear?

Comment: So how would you do it - if you wanted just one instance of the `Settings` class and just one instance of the `SystemController` ? I'm reading about shared pointers at the moment - but I'm unsure if this is the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is It Possible to Use a Shared Pointer for the Parent of a QObject?

No. There is no shared pointer which is a subclass of QObject. And I don't see why it will make sense.

> The reason I want to pass the memory location of the SystemController,
>   is the Controller class has important data already setup in the class,
>   which I wish to access without having to run all my initialisation
>   methods within it again.

Why don't you separate the notion of `SystemController settings` into another POD class\struct. Then you can have either

```
class SystemController : public QObject, public SystemSettings
```

or

```
class SystemController : public QObject
{
   SystemSettings m_settings;
   SystemSettings systemSettings() {m_settings};

}
```

and play around with the settings as you wish.

Comment: Actually I think I just realised what you meant. You mean I should create a SystemController settings class which would hold my variables in a simple POD?

Comment: yes, a class just to regroup thoses variables. No signals. no slots. no complex ***logic***. this `SystemSettings` class could be  sent in a signal by SystemController with the second design choice.

Comment: @UmNyobe, I think you should add "SystemSettings class could be sent in a signal by SystemController" to your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can shape your `SystemController` to [Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/2266412) and put `QMutex` guards to access `SystemController's` private data used in concurrent threads.

Comment: I'll try this again, but I remember when I did try it, the compiler threw up an error because it used the `Settings` singleton in its constructor. I'll give it another go. I was just curious to see if there was an alternate/better method than that